# Ankh SVN not adding new files to the solution in Visual Studio after updating to latest subversion

Tags: visual-studio, svn, ankhsvn

After taking an update of the .net project in visual studio using ankh SVN, it is not adding the new files that has been added by other developers directly to the my project solution.

Every time after updating, I need to manually click on those newly added files and include in the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure those files have been added in Project (.prj) file and it is checked-in into SVN by the other developer, and then get latest from SVN.